# Whatsapp, Keeping the number on the new phone but without the old sim card

Tags: sim-card, whatsapp-messenger

Whatsapp, Keeping the number on the new phone but without the old sim card.
Ok the situation is I love my old number and to be honest don't want to ask everybody to change my number again and again.
But I do not have the old sim card, and that bums me out. If there is any way to achieve this?

Comment: On a new device WhatsApp generally ask you to [verify your phone number](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20970873) by SMS, which will be a bit difficult without the SIM.

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp checks if there's a sim card installed at the time of boot. 
So as long as you have a sim card installed, it shouldn't be a problem to your whatsapp account (The old one)

I've switched sim cards and it hasn't affected my whatsapp account.
The problem of verification arises when you boot your phone without a sim card.

Answer (score 0):

You could move your phone number to your new sim card and just type it in WhatsApp, I did that. WhatsApp will ask you for your phone number and once you type it in it should let you log in without a problem. (It worked for me).